# Why do I need to set the max value to 101 in order for my basic guessing program to guess 100?

Tags: c++, logarithm

I found that in order to allow the guesser to guess `100`, I need to set the maximum value to `100`. I am confused by this, since if something is maximum `100`, doesn't that include `100`? Is there something wrong with my code? Can anyone explain? Noob here looking for some help. Thanks so much!
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char yes_or_no;
int guess = 0;

void guesser(int we_are_on, int max, int min)
{
  cin >> yes_or_no;
  if (yes_or_no == 'y')
    max = we_are_on;
  else if (yes_or_no == 'n')
    min = we_are_on;
  else
    cout << "Bad Input!\n";
  cout << "Max: " << max << " Min: " << min << " Running Guess: " << we_are_on;
  we_are_on = min + ((max-min) / 2);
  cout << "\nIs your number less than " << we_are_on << '?';
  if (max - min <= 1)
  {
    guess = we_are_on;
    return;
  }
  guesser(we_are_on, max, min);
}

int main() 
{
  cout << "Is your number less than 50?";
  guesser(50, 101, 1);
  cout << "\n Your number is " << guess;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because of integer truncation.

```
we_are_on= min + ((max-min)/2 );
```

Work this out for large numbers, such that `max = 100` and `min = 50`, and we get:

```
we_are_on= 50 + ((max-min)/2 );
         = 50 + ((100 - 50)/ 2);
         = 75
```

Now, if this guess is wrong, and we keep going higher, then this happens:

```
guesser(75, 100, 1);
we_are_on= 75 + ((100-75)/2 );
         = (int) 87.5
         = 87

guesser(87, 100, 1);
we_are_on= 87 + ((100-87)/2 );
         = (int) 93.5
         = 93

guesser(93, 100, 1);
we_are_on= 93 + ((100-93)/2 );
         = (int) 96.5
         = 96

guesser(96, 100, 1);
we_are_on= 96 + ((100-96)/2 );
         = 98

guesser(98, 100, 1);
we_are_on= 98 + ((100-98)/2 );
         = 99

guesser(99, 100, 1);
we_are_on= 99 + ((100-99)/2 );
         = (int) 99.5
         = 99
// And therefore...
guesser(99, 100, 1); // ad infinitum
```

And there's your problem.  If you just save the result directly into an `int`, the decimal component will be cut off entirely, instead of being rounded.  If you just want a quick-and-dirty fix, you could have it check for another special case.

```
if (min == 99) {
    guess = 100;
} else if (max - min <= 1) {
    guess = we_are_on;
} else {
    guesser(we_are_on, max, min);
}
```

I believe that should work.

---

Edit: Darn, StillLearning beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks both of you for putting up with this question. I really appreciate it, great explanation. I won't ever  forget  this tidbit!

Comment: You're welcome.  If you're having problems with an algorithm, it can sometimes be helpful to solve it manually; you might be able to see what's causing the problem that way.  Also, if you want to round a value instead of having it merely truncated, you could take a look at std::round(): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/  (Note that it may not be available in older compilers, if they're not fully C++11-compliant.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider `max = 100` and `min=99`

Then this line

```
we_are_on= min + ((max-min)/2 );
```

will be

```
we_are_on= 99 + ((100-99)/2 ) = 99 + (1/2) = 99 + 0 = 99
```

so you can't reach 100.

The problem is that the result of integer division is always truncated.

If you want rounding for integer division, you'll have to add half on the number you divide with first.

Example:

```
int x = 16;
int y = 10;  // must be an equal number in this example
int z = x/y; // z is 1 due to truncation
int w = (x + y/2)/y; // add y/2 before division with y => w is 2, i.e. rounding
```